# Motivation for measurable functions?

Tags: measure-theory

Here is the definition for Measurable Functions we used this year in our Measure Theory module.

> Let $Z$ be a set and $\mathscr{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $Z$.
>
> A function $f:Z \to \mathbb{R}$ is a Measurable Function if the set
>   $\{x \in Z: f(x) < \lambda\}$ belongs to $\mathscr{A}$ for every real number
>   $\lambda$.

**Question**

I am wondering what's the motivation\intuition behind this statement. What is so 'special' about $f(x)$ being greater than $\lambda$ belonging to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$?

**Edit: Update**

After working on it for a while...here is what I am starting to think...

**Part 1)**

Regarding a fuction $f:Z \to \mathbb{R}$ we would like to be able to measure an interval $I$ in the range $\mathbb{R}$. Ie. we would like $f^{-1}(I)$ to have a measure associated with it.

This can only happen if $f^{-1}(I)$ is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ over $Z$. If this is the case then if we have a measure $\mu: A \to [0, \infty]$ we will be able to compose $f^{-1}$ with $\mu$ and we can say $\mu \circ f^{-1} \in [0, \infty].$ I think my understanding is correct so far?

**Part 2)**

Now this is the part I would be less sure about...

We can determine if we have the correct conditions for the function $f$ to be measurable by checking if the set $\{x \in Z: f(x) < \lambda\ = f(x) \in [-\infty, \lambda)\}$ belongs to $\mathscr{A}$ for every real number $\lambda$. Why does this work? Well this is the part I am less sure about but here's how I view it -

Say we have an interval $I$ in the domain $\mathbb{R}$.

We can construct $I$ using $[-\infty, \lambda_1) \setminus  [-\infty, \lambda_2)$ for some $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}$

If $f^{-1}([-\infty, \lambda)) \in \mathscr{A}$ for all $\lambda$ then we will have that

$f^{-1}(I) = f^{-1}([-\infty, \lambda_1) \setminus  [-\infty, \lambda_2)) \in \mathscr{A}$ as $\forall \ A, B \in \mathscr{A}$ we have $A \setminus B \in \mathscr{A}$.

So is that the correct intuition for what is **special** about $f(x)$ being less than $\lambda$ belonging to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$? It lets us 'construct' intervals in the range that can be measured when mapped back to the domain?

Comment: equivalently you can say: if $S\subset\mathbb R$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets then $f^{-1}(S)\in A$.

Answer (score 1):

You know that there is an association between continuous functions and open sets, namely $f$ is continous iff the inverse image of each open set under $f$ is open. This statement can be generalized to any $A$-mearsurable functions, that is, we say that a function is $A$- mearuarble iff the inverse image of each open set of $\mathbb{R}$ is an $A$-measurable set.

The definition you give can be shown to be one equivalent case, in fact, it could well be $f(x) < \lambda, \ f(x) \ge \lambda$ or $f(x) \le \lambda$

Comment: I am already aware of the equivalent cases you mentioned and their proofs. I am looking for deeper information, namely why $f(x) < \lambda$ is 'special' and makes the function measurable.